# Retrieving PDF Data from parse database

Tags: objective-c, xcode, parse-server

I am trying to retrieve a PDF file I've uploaded to my database using Parse-Server. I've already uploaded the file successfully and I checked that it was actually in the database but I can't seem to download it/retrieve it in my app and viewing it in a `WKWebview`. The url is always equal to nil. how can I make the url equal to the PDF file I am trying to retrieve from the database.

I've already tried : `NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlString];`

but it wont load in the WKWebview

```
        [file2 getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {

                NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];
                 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];


                NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
                NSLog(@"REQUEST IS : %@",request);
                [self->_webview loadRequest:request];




            }else{
                NSLog(@"ERROR OCCURRED %@",error);
            }
        }];
```

Answer (score 0):

I Figured it out. The solution was to switch the WKWebview into a UIWebview and it worked perfectly!

```
[file2 getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
if (!error) {


    NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    [self->_webview loadData:data MIMEType:@"application/pdf" textEncodingName:urlString baseURL:url];




}else{
    NSLog(@"ERROR OCCURED %@",error);
}
```

}];